# I am trying to match an integer I have stored on a file that I loop through with a value I have stored in variable that is constantly changing

Tags: python-3.x, range

I have created a file that has many values in it. I am reading these values in to a variable(var1) as my program loops through the file. I then have another variable(var2) that is taking a float from an api. I would like a certain action to take place if the value in var2 is equal to the value in var 1. Seems simple. However, the value in var2 is a float - how best to remove the floating point and digits thereafter to take it just as an integer?

Having done this, I would then like to give a bit of leeway to the value in var1. So for example, I would like the condition to be met if the value in var2 was within a certain distance from var 1 rather than matching it integer for integer - eg. the condition would be met if var1 = 1000 and var2 = 1003. rather than them both having to be valued at 1000.

I think it may be possible by using the range function but I am not so sure how to go about it as of yet.

Comment: `math.floor()` and `math.ceil()` can round floats for you, then you just need to formulate a conditional, like `if var1 + buffer > var2 or var1 - buffer < var2: #doStuff`

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: lol yes of course.

Comment: @JDunken thank you, that is very useful, much appreciated.

Comment: @Ludwig Please do post what you have tried and the error message, if any.

Comment: Problem is solved. I used the int() and round() methods as suggested below and then created a variable with an acceptable error value that is met using the modulas of var1 /var2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to round your float.

1. int(): Truncates the float. int(3.1) = 3
2. round(): Rounds the floatto nearest integer. round(3.6) = 4
3. math.ceil(): Rounds the float up to the nearest integer. math.ceil(3.1) = 4
4. math.floor(): Rounds the float down to the nearest integer. math.floor(3.6) = 3

You can check the absolute value in the difference between `var2` wrapped in any of these and `var1`, and set an acceptable value for error.

```
import math

var1 = 1000
var2 = 1003.2

acceptable_error = 5

print(abs(int(var2) - var1) <= acceptable_error)
print(abs(round(var2) - var1) <= acceptable_error)
print(abs(math.ceil(var2) - var1) <= acceptable_error)
print(abs(math.floor(var2) - var1) <= acceptable_error)
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: Ah yes! I was on the right track as I was trying to use a value (5) rather than a variable. Very helpful methods also. Thank you sir.